# How to open 'This PC' using CMD or Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, directory

I need a way of opening the explorer at This PC , in the same way as opening in a windows explorer Gui, but I am incapable of this as using Explorer.exe in CMD opens quick access.

I tried opening it with a shortcut and that too failed.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Cheers

Comment: `explorer /e,root,::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`

Comment: ^ That just opens up the Documents library for me

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just like you can run `explorer.exe C:\` to open up the `C:` (or any other drive or folder path), you can also use a `file:` URI to open paths in Explorer as well. If you just specify the `file:` protocol without a directory (or specify `file:\\`), it will open `This PC`:

```
explorer file:
explorer file:\\
```

---

Note that you can also change the default Explorer location from `Quick Access` to `This PC` as well from `Folder Options`:

[image: Folder Options]

You can set this in the registry too if you're after automation to configure this. See my answer on [how you can use PowerShell to set the default launch folder in the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69188962/584676).

Answer (score 4):

My experience is that, the following should work:

From [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```dos
Start "" "%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe" /Select,"This PC"
```

From [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell):

```dos
Start "$Env:SystemRoot\explorer.exe" "/Select,'This PC'"
```

Comment: Technically very little, @BendertheGreatest, my experience is that invoking an explorer window is not instantaneous, `Start` therefore returns control back to the `cmd.exe` window a little quicker. _It also looks more in keeping with the alias for `Start-Process` in my now added `powershell.exe` example._

Comment: Invoking explorer Windows isn't instantaneous but the console also doesn't block until it opens. Doing some timing tests with `Measure-Command` in PowerShell shows both ways return to the shell in about the same time, with `explorer '/root,' edging out barely ahead between about 10-20 ms. Maybe your method is faster on a slower system but IMO the added complexity isn't worth the performance tradeoff.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this in cmd:

```
Explorer /root,
```

Answer (score 2):

On Powershell, we can do this:

```
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Namespace("").Self.InvokeVerb()
```

We create a com object of class Shell.Application, then call
.InvokeVerb() that invokes the default verb "open".

Or more rigourously, by defining ssfDRIVES constant (see Microsoft [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants))

```
Set-Variable ssfDRIVES -Option Constant -Value 0x11
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Namespace($ssfDRIVES).Self.InvokeVerb()
```

> ssfDRIVES 0x11 (17). Namespace points to My Computer—the virtual folder that
> contains everything on the local computer: storage devices, printers,
> and Control Panel. This folder can also contain mapped network drives.

Comment: This is an interesting approach to opening Explorer to `My PC`. However, I would caution others against using this approach unless you are using an *already existing* instance of `Shell.Application`. Otherwise, it's an unnecessary use of a COM object and there are simpler, less convoluted approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Command Prompt and type this in:

```
explorer =
```

Answer (score 1):

All of this comment uses Powershell 7, idk if it works on Windows Powershell 5.1. and ofc it's using Windows Terminal:

### Some background info

For documentation purposes mainly, you can skip to the next Header *(-->next h2)*

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$thisPCFolder = $shell.Namespace(0x11)
```

(0x11) is same as 20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D

so the second line is the same as

```
$thisPCFolder = $shell.NameSpace('::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}')
```

use whichever.

Take into account that `This PC` isn't an actual folder, it's a virtual one, so for that you have to use Shell.Application COM objects.

The `Shell.Application COM object` uses these numeric representations to access specific special folders and namespaces in the Windows Shell. Which is the first block code.

So `0x11` isn't the only one who works these constants **Windows Shell API** and can be found in the `Shlobj.h` header file, which is a part of the `Windows Software Development Kit (SDK)`. Like these constants:

- 0x00 - Desktop
- 0x02 - Programs
- 0x03 - Control Panel
- 0x04 - Printers
- 0x05 - My Documents (Documents)
- 0x06 - Favorites
- 0x07 - Startup Folder
- 0x08 - Recent Items
- 0x09 - Send To
- 0x0a - Recycle Bin
- 0x0b - Start Menu
- 0x0d - My Music
- 0x0e - My Videos
- 0x0f - Desktop (for a specific user)
- 0x10 - Control Panel (virtual folder)
- 0x11 - This PC (virtual folder)
- 0x12 - Network
- 0x13 - Fonts
- 0x14 - My Computer
- 0x15 - My Network Places

So you don't have to download any module or anything, you just need to have Powershell 7 and you should be good to execute the code on your machine.

So to enumerate the disks I did this:

```
# Create a new instance of Shell.Application
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application

# Get the "This PC" folder
$thisPCFolder = $shell.Namespace(0x11)

# Enumerate through the items in "This PC" folder
foreach ($item in $thisPCFolder.Items()) {
    # Display the name and path of each item
    $name = $thisPCFolder.GetDetailsOf($item, 0)
    $path = $thisPCFolder.GetDetailsOf($item, 217)
    Write-Output "$name : $path"
}
```

printing this on my Terminal when I execute it:

```
Local Disk (C:) :
name_of_your_disk_D (D:) :
```

you can skip this
As an example of usage on real code application you can read this and see how `0x11` is used [github code file](https://github.com/nosalan/powershell-mtp-file-transfer/blob/master/phone_backup.ps1) on `line 40` currently
........

Or you can just use `Start-Process C:\` or `Start-Process D:\` if you know already the name of your disk and then press `Alt + ↑`

### The real tutorial

But the answer you might really want is this, copy paste this block code on your PowerShell and see what happens:

```
# Use the Start-Process cmdlet to open "This PC" (My Computer) in Windows Explorer
Start-Process "explorer.exe" "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"
```

Now you could use an Alias for this last block code and then put it on $PROFILE so it applies to your shell **each time** you open it and **not only one session**. This how to do so:

- First corroborate if you have a $PROFILE:

```
Test-Path $PROFILE
```

- If `False` you need to create a file, run:

```
New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PROFILE -Force
```

- Now you need to open the notepad to insert the code:

```
notepad.exe $PROFILE
```

- Copy paste this on the last line if you already have some code

```
function MyPC {
    Start-Process "explorer.exe" "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"
}
```

- Restart you PowerShell 7 terminal, reload it using this command if you don't want to close your Terminal and open it again:

```
. $PROFILE
```

Now each time you use `MyPC` alias in your PowerShell 7 terminal it will open `This PC` in a new Windows Explorer window.

edit: so i just read the above answer (the most voted one on here) so basically you could just go to `Folder options` and change from `Home` to `This PC` and then just write `explorer` on your PowerShell and it will lead you to `This PC`.

sources: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/list-of-windows-11-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts.1075/