# How can I change the Folder Option "Open File Explorer To" with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am looking for a way to change this with a PowerShell script:

[image: Folder Options]

The default setting is **Quick Access** and I want **This PC**. I looked at some posts but nobody wants something like this.

How can I use PowerShell to change the **Folder Options** settings?

Comment: This question can be better asked on superuser

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `LaunchTo` property under the registry key `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`.

To do this, we can use the [Set-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet:

```
# Set up the parameters for Set-ItemProperty
$sipParams = @{
  Path  = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced'
  Name  = 'LaunchTo'
  Value = 1 # Set the LaunchTo value for "This PC"
}

# Run Set-ItemProperty with the parameters we set above
Set-ItemProperty @sipParams
```

---

There are three possible values this will take, so if you want to open **Quick Access** or **Downloads**, set the value to either of those numbers instead:

1. **This PC**
2. **Quick Access**
3. **Downloads**

The value for **Downloads** seems to be undocumented, but it does work. Any other values will result in an error when opening **File Explorer** about file associations.

Answer (score 0):

I test this code and it is work
And nuber 4 open onedrive

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34473333)